# Are there any more "quote" symbols to use as quotes?

Tags: python-3.x, quotes

Are there any "quote" symbols that you can use if you run out of them?

I know one can use `"` and `'` (and, perhaps a combination of them) like "''" (somehow)

A example of a "additional" "quote" symbol would be
`\"` inside quotes.

If I make a python script, and "used up" both `"` and `'`,   is there any more chars that I can use to indicate a quote?

Comment: How did you "use up" quote symbols? Could you give an example of what you're trying to do that requires "more quote symbols"? You may be looking for [raw string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: @Brian It's nice for exploit development. There's been multiple times where backticks have come in handy in JS due to all the nesting that can be required. Backtick quotes nested inside of single quotes nested inside of double quotes is a mess, but a real possibility.

Comment: thanks for helpping me as editing the post, etc. Really it helps! 
//DevOp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From what I can tell, `'` and `"` are the only quotes than can be used in a string literal. The [Lexical Analysis page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) contains this information:

```
shortstring     ::=  "'" shortstringitem* "'" | '"' shortstringitem* '"'
longstring      ::=  "'''" longstringitem* "'''" | '"""' longstringitem* '"""'
```

> In plain English: Both types of literals can be enclosed in matching single quotes (') or double quotes ("). They can also be enclosed in matching groups of three single or double quotes (these are generally referred to as triple-quoted strings).

Which suggests that those are the only two options.

Answer (score 0):

**No, `"` and `'` are the only quote characters in Python.**

If you run out of quote symbols you can "escape" quotes with a backslash(`\`), which will ignore the quotes and just make them part of the string.

For example, this would be a valid string:

```
print("hello \"bob\"")
```

This would return `'hello "bob"'`

Answer (score 0):

***No, their are no other quote chracters in Python for right now***
As far as I know `'` and `"` are tho only quote characters in python
but if you count a multi line string then it would look like this:

```
multiline = """
string
string
string
"""
```

and to make a list of them you would use:

```
multiline.splitlines()
```